# How to insert duplicate keys into b trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, b-tree

Please answer on b trees and not b+ trees.
I have 2 questions.

1. What happens when you insert duplicated keys to a b tree?
   For the following input how will the b tree with  t=3 look like? 
   1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2. Can a parent node in a b tree with t=3 look like this?
   1,1,4,10?
   If so will the son between the key "1" and the second key" 1" contain only the value "1" ?

Answer (score 5):

Just like hash tables, each node in the tree should store a link to a list of items associated with that key. You will store unique keys in the tree but the links will point to a list with possibly multiple items:

```
[node, key=1, ptr=l], l={1,1,1,1,1,1,1...}
```